# Creating a smaller array from a master array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of products. I want to create a second array that will be populated only when it each item in the first array match a criteria.
I know I can use a **for** loop, but I was hoping I could use one of the new array methods (**map, some, find, reduce**) but have been unsuccessful so far.
I have this:

```
var topProducts = products.find(function (product) {
    if (product.importance === importance) {
        return product;
    }
});
```

but it just returns the first product that it finds. I want it to return all products it finds (which will never been every product in the product array.

Comment: btw, find's callback should return a boolean. the method itselft returns then the element, if `true`, otherwises `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfect for filtering with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

> The **`filter()`** method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
var topProducts = products.filter(function (product) {
    return product.importance === importance;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the functional paradigm [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)